# Generics in a tree

Tags: c#, generics, tree

I have a segment class which is a node in the tree. There's no `Tree` class. The tree is just made up of segments.

```
public abstract class Segment 
{
    public List<Segment> Descendants { get; } => new List<Segment> Descendants;
    public abstract SegmentVisual VisualRepresentation { get; }
}
```

`SegmentVisual` is a class used to draw the segment to the screen. Both classes are abstract because I have different types of segments and each of it needs to be drawn differently.

Here's how `SegmentVisual` looks like:

```
public abstract class SegmentVisual : DrawingVisual 
{
    protected SegmentVisual(Segment owner){
        this.Owner = owner;
    }

    public Segment Owner { get; }
    public List<SegmentVisual> Descendants { get; } = new List<SegmentVisual>();

    public void Redraw()
    {
        this.RedrawItself();

        foreach (SegmentVisual visual in this.Visuals)
        {
            visual.Redraw();
        }
    }

    public abstract void RedrawItself();
}
```

Just like the Segment, the Visual also has descendants so that a single visual can be added to screen to draw itself and all of its descendants

Here's an implementation:

```
public class LineSegment : Segment
{
    public LineSegment()
    {
        this.VisualRepresentation = new LineSegmentVisual(this);
    }

    public override SegmentVisual VisualRepresentation { get; }

    public Pen Stroke { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public class LineSegmentVisual : SegmentVisual
{
    public LineSegmentVisual(LineSegment owner) // Resharper suggests this can be Segment base class
        : base(owner)
    {
    }

    public override void RedrawItself()
    {
        using (DrawingContext ctx = this.RenderOpen())
        {
            var owner = (LineSegment)this.Owner;
            ctx.DrawLine(owner.Stroke, this.Owner.Position, this.Owner.ControlPointPos);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is with the last class. You can see the ReSharper suggestion. And I am not feeling very good with down casting all the time. If I had to retrieve the owner at some other place, I would have to downcast to get the Stroke property again.

If I make `SegmentVisual` generic `SegmentVisual<T>`, with its owner being `T`, it introduces a new obstacle because now the `SegmentVisual` can only contain descendants of `SegmentVisual<T>` which should not be the case because I want it to contain any type of `SegmentVisual`, I just want the owner to be strongly typed.

I just want the `SegmentVisual` to be able to correspond to a specific class so that its `Owner` property is strongly typed. I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new` to declare strongly typed `Owner` in your subclass:

```
public class LineSegmentVisual : SegmentVisual
{
    new LineSegment Owner { get { return (LineSegment)base.Owner; } }

    public LineSegmentVisual(Segment owner)
        : base(owner)
    {
    }

    public override void RedrawItself()
    {
        using (DrawingContext ctx = this.RenderOpen())
        {
            var owner = this.Owner;
            ctx.DrawLine(owner.Stroke, this.Owner.Position, this.Owner.ControlPointPos);
        }
    }
}
```

This way `base.Owner` will be casted each time you call `this.Owner`, but at least you'll avoid repetitive code.

---

**Second** way is to use inheritance. Declare `SegmentVisual` with basic functionality

```
abstract class SegmentVisual
{
    public List<SegmentVisual> Descendants { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

and `OwnedSegmentVisual` with strongly typed owner

```
abstract class OwnedSegmentVisual<TOwner>: SegmentVisual where TOwner: Segment
{
    public TOwner Owner { get; private set; }

    protected OwnedSegmentVisual(TOwner owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }
}
```

`Owner` can be used in subclasses without casting and common functionality can just use `SegmentVisual`.

---

**Third** way is to use generics covariance, but you'll have to declare interfaces for your types:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sv = new LineSegmentVisual();
        sv.Descendants = new List<ISegmentVisual<Segment>> { new SquareSegmentVisual() };
    }
}


abstract class Segment {}

class LineSegment : Segment {}

class SquareSegment: Segment {}

interface ISegmentVisual<out TOwner>
{
    TOwner Owner { get; }

    List<ISegmentVisual<Segment>> Descendants { get; }
}

class LineSegmentVisual : ISegmentVisual<LineSegment>
{
    public LineSegment Owner { get; set; }
    public List<ISegmentVisual<Segment>> Descendants { get; set; }
}

class SquareSegmentVisual : ISegmentVisual<SquareSegment>
{
    public SquareSegment Owner { get; set; }
    public List<ISegmentVisual<Segment>> Descendants { get; set; }
}
```

---

Hope, this would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look later tonight and inform you :)

Comment: I used the second method, and it solved the problem . Thank s:)

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support return type variance. That is, the following is not possible:

```
class Foo
{
    virtual Base Owner{ get; }
}

class Bar: Foo
{
    override Derived Owner { get; } // where Dervided: Base
}
```

You will get a compile time error informing you that `Derived` does not override any suitable method. I find the lack of this feature in C# a bit annoying to be honest and although its been on the line a few times for future versions it has never made the cut. To be honest, competing features have been up to date quite a bit more interesting and useful.

IMO you have two reasonable options here. One is to hide `Owner`:

```
class Bar: Foo
{
    new Derived Owner { get { return base.Owner as Derived; } // where Derived: Base
}
```

The other is using explicitly implemented interfaces:

```
interface IOwnable
{
    Base Owner { get; }
}

class Foo: IOwnable
{
    Base IOwnable.Owner { get; }
}

class Bar: Foo
{
    Derived Owner { get { return ((IOwnable)base).Owner as Derived; } // where Derived: Base
}
```